# Change the default swipe curve of PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to change the default swipe curve on the `pageView` widget, I can easily do that by using the `controller.animateTo` and specifying the curve I want to use. but I couldn't find how to do so for the default swiping.

the pageView doesn't have a curve attribute in its constructor. how to do it then ?

Comment: check `PageView.physics`

Comment: It doesn't say how to do that either, and it doesn't have any curve options in its constructor. can you link to some tutorial if there any ?